# Hardwiring an old Friedland 454 doorbell chime. HELP!

Tags: electrical, wiring, old-house, doorbell

Hi I have an old doorbell chime that is run off batteries.  I believe it is the Friedland 454.  I would like to attach a ring doorbell to it but don't think it will work as its not hardwired.  So would like to ideally hardwire it and also not sure if I will need to purchase a transformer or if there's one built in.  I know it would be easier to buy a new chime and use that but I am a little attached to this chime.  I have attached a photo.  Any help or advice  would be greatly received.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: `if there's one built in` ... built into what?

Comment: Into the chime box pictured

Comment: you would see it then ... there're some batteries and a solenoid

Answer (score 1):

The chime operates on 6 VDC, probably requiring a few amperes to activate those solenoids. There is a circuit diagram at [DIYnot](https://www.diynot.com/diy/threads/can-anyone-identify-the-terminals-on-a-friedland-454-chime.471633/), and a discussion at [DIY StackExchange](https://www.diynot.com/diy/threads/can-anyone-identify-the-terminals-on-a-friedland-454-chime.471633/), but basically:

- Connect 6 volt DC power supply providing at least 2 amperes, such as one from [this list](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=6%20vdc%20power%20supply&crid=SR9VM5LWEL43&sprefix=6%20vdc%20power%20supply) to terminals 0 and 3. If 2 amps is insufficient, add a large electrolytic capacitor across those terminals, observing polarity.
- Connect a piece of wire between terminals 2 and 4.
- Connect the front door button to terminals 0 and 1 for repeating chime.
- Connect back door button to 0 and 2 for *ding* on press, *dong* on release.

**N.B.:** There are some safety hazards associated with this bell:

- A transformer can provide enough current to destroy the solenoid, or even cause a fire.
- A mercury switch is used to make the chime repeat. Should that little glass bulb containing metallic mercury break, there would be a serious hazardous material spill; the [vapor is highly toxic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_poisoning). You might consider disposing that switch at you communities hazardous materials site, and just have the single *ding... dong* chime.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  ohh dear scary stuff .... i think i might just buy a new chime and leave this as it is